# Genus von Vereinen

Tags: gender, abbreviation

Wenn der Grundname eines eingetragenen Vereins nicht männlich ist (sagen wir: "Dingenskirchengruppe e.V."), wie heißt es dann in *formellem* Deutsch (ggf. sogar Juristen-, Beamtendeutsch) richtig?

- "Mitglied des Dingenskirchengruppe e.V." wegen V. = **der** Verein
- "Mitglied der Dingenskirchengruppe e.V." wegen ...-gruppe = **die** Gruppe

Comment: Ich denke mal, dass es davon abhängt, wie du es liest. Wenn du das „e.V.“ mitliest, dann ist es männlich. Wenn du das „e.V.“ nicht mitliest, dann ist es hier weiblich. Ich würde niemals das „e.V.“ mitlesen, weil es kein Teil des Namens, sondern ein Attribut, das von außen vergeben und auch wieder entzogen werden kann.

Comment: Mein Gefühl ist klar pro "der"  für Verein. Theoretishc ist ja das davor nur der Name... und man würde auch nicht sagen "die Kirchengruppe Benz" sondern "der Kirchengruppe-Benz"

Comment: Am Rande: "e.V." aber mit Leerzeichen: "e. V."

Comment: Manche Vereine sind einfach ungeniesbar.

Comment: @unor: Wenn man das Leerzeichen weglässt geht man sicher, dass der Ausdruck nicht getrennt wird. Dafür gibt es zwar geschützte Leerzeichen, aber nicht jedes Programm derartiges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das einzige Offizielle, was ich hierzu finden konnte, ist § 65 BGB:

> Mit der Eintragung erhält der Name des Vereins den Zusatz „eingetragener Verein“.

Die Abkürzung ist also schon mal nicht offiziell (siehe hierzu auch [die Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verein#Eingetragener_Verein), zweiter Absatz) und insbesondere ist »eingetragener Verein« ein Zusatz. Ausgeschrieben also z. B.:

> Die Dingenskirchengruppe, eingetragener Verein, traf sich gestern.

Auch sonst würde ich es sprachlich als Zusatz behandeln, denn die Alternative

> Die Dingenskirchengruppe eingetragener Verein traf sich gestern.

ergibt keinen Sinn, auch nicht mit *der* als Artikel¹. Es liegt nun in der Natur von Zusätzen, dass sie problemlos weggelassen werden können und insbesondere das Geschlecht des Ergänzten nicht beeinflussen. »Mitglied des Dingenskirchengruppe e. V.« ist also in etwa so sinnvoll wie »Nächster Halt: Neue Friedhof, Endhaltestelle«.

Alternativ von der anderen Seite aufgezäumt: Wenn man *e. V.* nicht nur mitliest, sondern auch die Abkürzung auflöst, dann entsteht nur dann etwas Sinnvolles, wenn man es als Zusatz liest. Also kann das Geschlecht nicht beeinflusst werden.

Wenn nun umgekehrt der Verein vorangestellt wird (um z. B. die Rechtsform zu betonen) wird der eigentliche Name des Vereins zum Zusatz bzw. Nachtrag, z. B.:

> Der eingetragene Verein, Dingenskirchengruppe, traf sich gestern.²

(Und hier würde auch niemand auf die Idee kommen, von »die eingetragene Verein« zu sprechen.)

---

¹ Und selbst nicht wenn der Name des Vereins männlich ist, z. B.: „Der Verbund für Dingens eingetragener Verein traf sich gestern.“
² Kommata optional nach § 77 E1 der Rechtschreibregeln.

Answer (score 1):

Ich stimme dem Kommentar von [Toscho](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2553/toscho) zu: Abhängig davon, ob du das e. V. mitliest oder nicht, ändert sich das Geschlecht.

Allerdings handelt es sich dabei um den Eigennamen des Vereins und das Geschlecht ist deshalb zusätzlich davon abhängig, wie der Name in den geschriebenen oder ungeschriebnen Leitlinien des Vereins aufgefasst wird. Als ehemaliges Vorstandsmitglied des "Hochschulradio Aachen" kann ich mich erinnern, dass wir öfter auch "*das* Hochschulradio Aachen e. V." geschrieben haben, wenn wir gegenüber Außenstehenden zwar unsere Rechtsform deutlich machen die Marke "(das) Hochschulradio Aachen" aber nicht verfälschen wollten. Falsch klingt es in meinen (parteiischen) Ohren jedenfalls nicht.

Ich würde also sagen, dass du sogar im formellen Schriftdeutschen wegen des Eigennamens da alle Freiheiten hast. Wenn es wirklich, wirklich formell wird,  also im juristischen Bereich, wo die Rechtsform entscheidender ist als die Marke, dann würde ich vielleicht auf *der* xyz e. V. zurückgreifen.