# Welches Pronomen bei Firmennamen?

Tags: grammar, gender, pronoun, proper-noun

Gibt es eine Regel für die Verwendung des richtigen Pronomens bei Firmennamen?

Ein Beispielsatz, den ich übersetzen möchte und bei dem ich auf diese Frage gestoßen bin:

> With business growing steadily, **their** old ERP solution was not able to keep up. See how we helped [company name] gain supply chain efficiencies and visibility over **their** entire business.

Würdet ihr *their* mit *ihre* oder *seine* übersetzen oder verwendet man gar kein Pronomen und wiederholt stattdessen den Firmennamen?

Comment: Ähnlich: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/genus-von-vereinen

Comment: Man kann die Frage auf „juristische Personen“ verallgemeinern. Die Geschlechtskongruenz betrifft nicht nur Pronomen, sondern auch Nomina-actionis, bspw. ist eine AG vor Gericht eher _Klägerin_ als _Kläger_. Das wird allerdings nicht überall und immer durchgehalten, daher wird dann das Maskulinum generisch verwendet (und auch eher selten kritisiert).

Comment: Wie ist denn der Firmenname?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pronomen passen sich dem Numerus und Genus des Nomens an, das sie ersetzen, auch in diesem Fall. Ohne zu wissen, wie die Firma *korrekt* heißt, sind Fehler vorprogrammiert.

Manchmal sind Genus und Numerus einfach zu erkennen:

- Münchner Stadtwerke (f, pl)
- Deutsche Bank (f, sg)
- Bäckerei Schneider (f, sg)

Manchmal dagegen muss man recherchieren:

- SAP (?, ?, zumindest auf den ersten Blick)

Denn: Firmennamen leiden im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch häufig unter [Ellipsen](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik)) der Rechtsform, d.h. Teile wie *AG* oder *GmbH* fallen weg. Das sind jeweils *Gesellschaften*, also feminin - was sich in benutzten Artikeln und Pronomen niederschlägt. Ähnliches gilt für *Genossenschaft*.

Also korrekt: *Die* SAP SE.

Es gibt auch mehrdeutige Fälle:

Während Restaurants, Hotels und Cafés i.a. Neutrum sind, gibt es Fälle, bei denen Namensteile "pronomenbestimmend" werden weil der funktionsbeschreibende Teil "Hotel" o.ä. häufig entfällt. Beispiel:

- *Der* Bayerische Hof.

Benutzt man *Hotel* dagegen mit, wird es

- *das* Hotel Bayerischer Hof.

Comment: SAP ist inzwischen eine SE (Societas Europaea). ;-) Abgesehen davon ändert sich die Verwendung normalerweise, wenn an einen Namen mit offensichtlichem Genus/Numerus die Rechtsform angehängt wird: *Die Stadtwerke München haben*, *Die Stadtwerke München GmbH hat*.

Comment: @chirlu danke, edit erledigt. Immerhin Gesellschaft bleibt Gesellschaft ;-)

Comment: Der Plural von Werk ist Werke und wird mit 'die' gebildet, wie auch 'die Männer', aber Werk ist dennoch sächlich. Der Plural hat keinen Einfluss auf das Geschlecht, wohl aber auf das Pronomen.

Comment: Ja, ok, und wie würdest Du dann den Satz aus der Frage formulieren? Insbesondere fände ich interessant, ob man wirklich z.B. sagen würde "Ich arbeite als Berater bei den Stadtwerken. Durch den beständigen Zuwachs an neuen Kunden konnte ihr (deren?) ERP-System nicht mehr mithalten." Oder spezieller "das ERP-System ihrer Finanzabteilung"? In beiden Fällen würde ich über das "ihr" stolpern. "Deren" fände ich da einfacher.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin der Meinung, die Übersetzung mit *ihr/e* mit Bezug auf *sie (they)* klingt zu salopp oder umgangssprachlich. Ich würde Folgendes ausprobieren:

> Während das Geschäft ständig wächst, konnte sich die firmeneigene ERP-Solution nicht durchsetzen. Sehen Sie, wie wir der Company GmbH dabei geholfen haben, die Effizienz *ihrer* (1) Anlieferungsketten zu verbessern und Überblick über *ihr* (1) gesamtes Geschäftsfeld zu gewinnen.

**(1)** Das *ihr* kommt von "***die*** GmbH"

Würde man sich wiederum nicht auf die Rechtsform des Unternehmens beziehen, würde vielleicht eher so etwas daraus:

> Während das Geschäft ständig wächst, konnte sich die firmeneigene ERP-Solution nicht durchsetzen. Sehen Sie, wie wir Audi dabei geholfen haben, die Effizienz *der* Anlieferungsketten zu verbessern und Überblick über *das* gesamte Geschäftsfeld zu gewinnen.´

Ich habe hier extra den Namen einer großen, wohlbekannten Firma genommen, damit der grammatikalische Effekt stärker zur Geltung kommt.

Comment: Das Femininum ist nicht beschränkt auf eine GmbH, sonderen n findet sich auch bei anderen Rechtsformen. Deshalb spricht man ja auch vom Mutterkonzern und der Tochterfirma. Man kann also immer einen weiblichen Artikel wählen und muss nicht auf Ausweichmanöver zurückgreifen (*...wie wir Audi dabei geholfen haben, **ihre** Effizienz der...*).

Comment: @Takkat Bist Du sicher, dass **ihre** sich dann noch auf einen weiblichen Singular bezieht und nicht auf einen Plural ("die Leute bei Audi")?

Comment: Ja! Genau die Version mit "Leute bei Audi" klingt für mich salopp. Dumm nur, das die beiden Formen im Deutschen zusammenfallen.

Comment: Ja, ich bin sicher. Jede Firma ist feminin singular und dann ist der Bezug eindeutig.

Comment: @Takkat: Wenn man dann aber nicht explizit von der Audi AG, sondern nur von "Audi" spricht, wirkt der darauffolgende Bezug mit "ihre" aber extrem holprig.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: was soll daran holprig sein? Nicht jede Firma ist eine GmbH, AG, KG oder was noch alles. *Aldi Süd hat ihren Umsatz verdoppelt* ist korrekt.

Comment: @Takkat: Zudem scheint bei manchen Firmennamen ein anderes Genus gebräuchlicher zu sein, beispielsweise soll ["Aldi *seine* Mitarbeiter" überwacht haben](http://www.wiwo.de/unternehmen/handel/kontrollwahn-aldi-soll-mitarbeiter-gaengeln/6573586.html) (Hervorhebung von mir).

Comment: @Takkat: Nicht jede Firma. Eindeutige Gegenbeispiele sind _das BHW_ (ehemals _Beamtenheimstättenwerk_),  und umgangssprachlich _der Benz_ (_Ich schaff beim Benz_).

Comment: @Takkat: "Aldi Süd hat ihren Umsatz verdoppelt" ruft in mir nur das Bedürfnis hervor, die Gegenfragen "Wessen Umsatz? Wer ist 'sie'?" zu stellen, wohingegen "Aldi Süd hat seinen Umsatz verdoppelt." keine solche Zweifel aufkommen lässt. Das scheinen [FAZ](http://www.faz.net/agenturmeldungen/unternehmensnachrichten/aldi-australien-enthuellt-gewinn-in-drei-jahren-mehr-als-verdoppelt-13699682.html) ("Aldi Australien steigerte seinen Vorsteuergewinn ..."), [Media-Saturn](http://www.media-saturn.com/de/DE/Career/WhatWeOffer/WeHereInIngolstadt/LivingInIngolstadt/Seiten/Default.aspx) über sich ...

Comment: ... selber ("Media-Saturn hat seinen Hauptsitz in Ingolstadt."), [Focus](http://www.focus.de/finanzen/news/wirtschaftsticker/unternehmen-rewe-verkauft-seine-supermaerkte-in-italien_id_3957877.html) ("Rewe verkauft seine Supermärkte in Italien
") und andere ähnlich zu sehen. Sogar [Beispiele für eindeutig weibliche Firmennamen](http://www.finanzen.net/nachricht/aktien/Geldanlage-Report-Bijou-Brigitte-enttaeuscht-mit-schwachem-Ausblick-auf-das-Jahr-2015-Irritierende-Kommunikation-mit-den-Anlegern-4320390) ("... empfiehlt Bijou Brigitte dringend, seine Kommunikation ...") finden sich.

Comment: @Takkat Du gehst also bei der Aldi einkaufen? Und die Lidl? Oder in die Rewe? Oder in die Kaufland? – Ich bezweifel das irgendwie.

Comment: Da es sich bei Firmennamen um eine "Firma", ein "Unternehmen", einen "Konzern", eine "Aktiengesellschaft" etc. handeln kann, denke ich, dass man nicht pauschal sagen kann, 'bei einer Firma wird immer das Femininum verwendet'. In dem Fall meines Beispielsatzes, muss ich mir mit dem erstmaligen Einschub von "Firma" oder "Unternehmen" aushelfen, um dann das entsprechende Pronomen "ihre" oder "seine" zu wählen.

Comment: @nelly das ist richtig. Sobald man explizit *Unternehmen* (n) oder *Konzern* (m) hinzufügt, muss man das entsprechende Genus verwendend. Wenn dies nur in Gedanken erfolgte, kann man das entsprechende Genus nehmen. Wenn aber beides nicht vorliegt oder unbekannt ist, gilt in der Regel ein Femininum. In juristischem Kontext sowieso. Man sollte bitte nicht Ausnahmen als Beweis für die Ungültigkeit einer Regel hernehmen.

Comment: @Takkat Bitte versteh mich nicht falsch, mein Kommentar war nicht als Beweis für die Ungültigkeit der Regel gemeint, sondern eher als eine Erweiterung.

Comment: @nelly: Dein Kommentar nicht, andere aber schon.

Comment: @Takkat: "Wenn aber beides nicht vorliegt oder unbekannt ist, gilt in der Regel ein Femininum." - und genau das halte ich für falsch. Dass im juristischen Kontext als Ausnahme immer die (feminine) Rechtsform angenommen wird, ändert nichts daran, dass es im allgemeingebräuchlichen (auch förmlichen!) Deutsch einfach nicht üblich ist, stets das Femininum anzunehmen, wie ich anhand diverser Beispiele dargelegt habe.

Answer (score 1):

In Bezug auf die Rechtsform (Gesellschaft mbH, Aktiengesellschaft, Kommanditgesellschaft) wird meistens die feminine Form verwendet (i.S.v. die Firma/Gesellschaft) Die häufigste Gebrauchsform (bsd. bei Unsicherheit) ist jedoch meistens eine ohne bestimmten Artikel.

> **Die** Siemens Aktien**gesellschaft** hat ...
>
> **Der** Siemens-**Konzern** hat eine PM veröffentlicht.
>
> Siemens hat eine Pressemitteilung veröffentlicht.

Bei einem gleichzeitigen Markennamen (Aldi, Lidl, Penny) wird oft die männliche Form genutzt. Man bezieht sich auf "den Supermarkt", also das Objekt, was man mit dem Namen in Verbindung bringt, nicht die Rechtsform. Der eigentliche Begriff "Supermarkt" wird dann meist weggelassen.

> Ich gehe im Aldi einkaufen.
>
> Ich gehe zu Butter Beck.
>
> Der Ulrich hat die größte Auswahl.

Zusammengefasst lässt sich sagen, dass die Wahl des Artikels vom Geschlecht des oft ausgelassenen Zusatzbegriffes abhängt. Meistens wird im Kontext von Firmen jedoch die weibliche Form genutzt, da die Rechtsform in den meisten Fällen "**eine** Gesellschaft" ist. :)

Comment: Ein Teil der Antworten wurde nicht geladen. Stephie hat das bereits wunderbar erklärt.

Answer (score -1):

Das erste **their** ist mit **ihre** zu übersetzen, da es sich auf **IHRE** *ERP solution* bezieht.

Das zweite **their** ist mit **ihr** zu übersetzen, da es sich auf **IHR** *entire business* bezieht.

Comment: Das kommt dann ganz darauf an, wie man _solution_ und _business_ wiedergibt. Hat aber wenig mit der Frage zu tun, in der es letztlich um _ihr_ vs. _sein_ geht.

Comment: @chirlu Ich dachte, die Frage ist nach ihr / sein oder Firmenname wiederholen. In dem Fall passt die Antwort halbwegs, ist aber ohne Erklärung nicht sonderlich hilfreich.