# Gender of the company name "Deutsche Wohnen"

Tags: gender

Why isn't the company called *Deutsches Wohnen*? It is *das Wohnen*, neutral, if I'm not mistaken.

*Deutsche Wohnen* (or *Deutsche wohnen*, but capitalized because it's a name) would mean for me "Germans live". *Deutsches Wohnen* would imply for me "German living (standards)".

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25180/welches-pronomen-bei-firmennamen

Comment: @Eller That is plainly wrong.

Comment: @Eller  It is not only wrong, as Jonathan stated. It is so disturbing that I cannot find sleep any more and would like to ask you to remove that comment.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I don't see any problem with that interpretation. It could be even a verb if not capitalized.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50031/artikel-of-mcdonalds

Comment: @Eller   Yes, that's why it is so disturbing: it is theoretically possible to say that "die Wohnen" is a a plural of "das Wohnen". But this form is never used, and nobody familiar with German would try to use it. It is a merely hypothetical, imaginary form. Moreover, in terms of meaning, there is no use of a plural of a verb. "Das Wohnen" (or any other activity) is not countable, so a plural makes no sense.

Comment: Rule of thumb: companies are feminime.

Comment: @peterh How does it explain why "deutsche" in company's name is feminin? What is the noun for it?

Comment: @Eller "Firma". Native speakers have explained to me once so: "die Microsoft", "die Siemens", weil sie tatsächlich "die Microsoft Firma", "die Siemens Firma" denken, sagen aber das letzte Wort nicht.

Comment: Die Gesellschaft.

Comment: Related (general question): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61451/

Answer (score 3):

Proper names don't have to follow grammar conventions.

Aside from that, company names often feature an implicit

> die Gesellschaft – the corporation

and *die Deutsche Wohnen* is no exception. That's why it's feminine.

Comment: In other words, it is one of the many mannerisms of the real estate business. They have plenty of peculiar words or ways to use words that in a context of normal conversation are simply idiotic.

Comment: So, it would be something akin to 'Deutsche Wohnengesellschaft', 'German housing society'? Not very expressive, but as inane as "American Apparel"

Comment: *Red Blazer Realty*

Comment: Wie man bei Wikipedia leicht nachlesen kann, ist die Deutsche Wohnen eine Aktiengesellschaft. In der Abkürzung klingt es in der Tat schräg, aber idiotisch ist es nicht.

Comment: Why then is the adjective in RWE AG neuter? Rheinisch-Westfälische**s** Elektrizitätswerk AG.

Comment: People say **das RWE**? I can't follow.

Comment: (the question is not about _die_ or _das_ if you remember) And that's the point  - why it's _die Deutsche Wohnen AG_ but _die Rheinisch-Westfälische**s** Elektrizitätswerk AG_? Both constructions are absolutely equal - die Adjective Neuter-Noun AG. But the adjective is feminine in one case and neuter in another. How that?

Comment: I think that's because it was neuter before, before it became an AG.

Comment: It was an AG from the very beginning. "[Die Geschichte des RWE beginnt mit seiner Gründung als Rheinisch-Westfälisches Elektrizitätswerk AG 1898 in Essen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschichte_des_RWE)". BTW note "des" in the article title.

Comment: Sorry, no clue then. As I wrote, proper names do not have to follow grammar conventions.

Answer (score 3):

The full name is "Deutsche Wohnen AG", where AG means it is based on stocks.
AG stands for Aktiengesellschaft (a feminine).

As in the stock market this is obvious, the AG is omitted.

Comment: What about RWE which is Rheinisch-Westfälische**s** Elektrizitätswerk AG?

Comment: @Annatar My comment (as well as the question) is not about the article but about the adjective. How do you explain why it's "rheinisches" and not "rheinische" although it's an AG too?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's pretty easy why the "Deutsche Wohnen SE" is called this way and it has nothing to do with grammar.

> The *Deutsche Wohnen* was founded in 1998 by the *Deutsche Bank*.

You see, the subsidiary was named like the parent company the *Deutsche Bank*. Including all grammar and naming conventions.

Edit:

Current [other](http://www.bkkdb.de/de/tochterunternehmen.htm) [subsidiaries](https://www.db.com/ir/de/download/Deutsche_Bank_Geschaeftsbericht_2018.pdf) following this kind of CI are

> Deutsche Asset Management Investment GmbH
>
> Deutsche Australia Limited, Sydney
>
> Deutsche Securities Inc., Tokyo
>
> Deutsche Immobilien Leasing GmbH
>
> Deutsche Familiy Office GmbH

Comment: This should be the top answer. *Deutsche* here is used like a brand name in line with the corporate identity of *Deutsche Bank*, made up by some bankers that didn't really care about the grammatical derivation.

Comment: NB: *Deutsche* is not uncommonly used in the U.S., especially in the finance industry, to refer to *Deutsche Bank*.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume (unlike other answetrs) that your question is about the gender of "Deutsche" not the gender of the name itself.

Since it's a name, it could be quite arbitrary. And yes, "Deutsche Wohnen" would mean that Germans live.

The full name is "Deutsche Wohnen AG" and in my opinion it's a play of words. One might understand `deutsche "Wohnen AG"` as in " a stock market oriented property company that happens to be German" or `"Deutsche Wohnen" AG` as in "A company named 'Deutsche Wohnen' that happens to be an 'AG'". And what is wrong with "Deutsche Wohnen"? I'd even say that "Deutsches Wohnen" would be problmatic since it might imply hostility toward strangers/foreighners and one would need to explain what is German about it and why German is inherently good etc. On the other hand one can't deny that Germans live and that a German property company is somewhat related to that.