# Der Die Das <Brand> - Company names

Tags: gender

What is the Gender of a company name?

What does it depend on?

Let's say `Microsoft` for that matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, proper names (like brand names) have no gender (and thus no article in front of them), but well-established brand names might adopt gender over time (Publicity agencies even *recommend* adding gender to your brand name as this creates the impression that it might be a well-established one).

There's the easy and the tricky cases - the easy ones are where the brand name is containing or alluding to a noun that has gender in German:

- die *Allianz*(-Versicherung)
- die *Hamburg-Mannheimer* (Versicherung)
- der *Springer*-Verlag
- die *Volksbank*

More tricky are acronyms - but still, if you expand them, you might be ending up with a definitive gender

- die *BASF* ("Badische-Anilin-und-Soda-**Fabrik**")
- die *Degussa* ("Deutsche Gold- und Silber-Scheide**anstalt**")
- der *TÜV* ("Technischer Überwachungs**verein**")
- der/die *DEKRA* ("Deutscher Kraftfahrzeug-Überwachungs**verein**")  Note this one is a bit more tricky than the above, because few people actually know to what the abbreviation expands - instinctively, they will use female because the "-a" ending somewhat forces your Latin heritage memory to use female.

Then there is another class for company and brand names that are no abbreviations. Often gender has been adopted over time, especially for brand names that are old and well-established, sometimes more than one gender is possible:

- Die *Lufthansa* (Words ending in "-a" in German very often assume female)
- die/das *Nutella*
- die *Air France* (airways are generally female for some reason, also applies to first item)

As you might see, we're slowly wandering away from safe grounds into non-rule territory - Here, the German language very often simply pulls back to my initial statement and assumes no gender at all, *avoiding* any possible problems. [example sentences taken from Wikipedia articles]

*Microsoft* as in your example is apparently one of those - You simply avoid any construct that assumes a specific gender:

> Microsoft wurde am 4. April 1975 gegründet. Das Unternehmen [not: er, sie oder es!] hat etwa 148.000 Mitarbeiter und ist der größte Softwarehersteller der Welt.

If you absolutely want and need gender, then try and derive one from the company's legal denomination, in most cases you will be ending up with "Gesellschaft" (or "corporation"), thus ending up with female.

> die *Microsoft* Corporation

The same is BTW true for some well-established German brands as well:

> Die *Daimler-Benz AG*

But you will still encounter the "evade" strategy as above in follow-up sentences.

Comment: Regarding Lufthansa: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Hansa

Comment: "die Allianz(-Versicherung)" - wobei "die Allianz" natürlich für sich genommen bereits ein feminines Substantiv ist und man den Umweg über die "Versicherung" erst gar nicht gehen muss.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ganz so einfach ist das gar nicht. Denn warum ist dann *Volkswagen* (nicht das Auto, sondern die Firma) nicht maskulin?

Comment: @tofro: Bei Unternehmen, die physische Produkte herstellen, bezeichnet "<Artikel> <Unternehmsname>" häufig das Produkt, nicht das Unternehmen. Das hat aber mE nichts damit zu tun, dass "Allianz" an sich ja bereits ein feminines Substantiv ist. Anders also als bei dem ebenfalls von dir genannten Beispiel der Hamburg-Mannheimer lässt sich also direkt aus dem Namen "Allianz" selber der feminine Artikel ableiten, ohne dass man eine Erklärung über ein angehängtes "-Versicherung" suchen müsste.

Comment: +1 for the very differenciated analysis covering the main aspects in an exhaustive way. I would add, that AG's (_die Aktiengesellschaft_) and GmbH's (_die Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung_) seem to be feminin as well, for instance _Die Deutsche Wohnen_.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Du hast mich, glaube ich, nicht verstanden: Wenn du argumentierst, dass "die Allianz" (das Unternehmen) deswegen ein Femininum ist, weil "die Allianz" für sich genommen ein feminines Substantiv ist, dann argumentiere ich analog (fälschlich), dass "Volkswagen" (das Unternehmen) ein Maskulinum sein muß, weil "der Wagen" für sich genommen ein maskulines Substantiv ist. Wie man sieht, funktioniert das nicht richtig.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das habe ich versucht, mit "in most cases, you will be ending up with *Gesellschaft*" zu sagen.

Comment: @tofro: Ich hab' dich denke ich schon verstanden, aber ich teile deine Schlussfolgerung nicht. Ja, meiner Meinung nach sagt man allein schon deswegen "die Allianz" und nicht der oder das Allianz, weil das Wort "Allianz" selber bereits feminin ist. Daraus folgt meiner Meinung nach jedoch *nicht* automatisch, dass "Volkswagen" maskulin sein sollte, denn einerseits sind (deine Aussage) Markennamen wie anderen Eigennamen auch zunächst geschlechtslos und nur einzelne nehmen überhaupt ein Geschlecht an, und andererseits wird (meine Ergänzung) der Name mit geschlechtsspezifischem Artikel im Fall ...

Comment: ... von Unternehmen, die physisch greifbare Produkte herstellen, normalerweise für das Produkt selber verwendet und ist somit bereits "belegt" bzw. steht als Bezeichnung für das Unternehmen nicht mehr zur Verfügung.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dann ist ja gut, dass du meine Argumentation verstehst. Weniger gut ist, dass du ihr nicht folgst, aber damit muss ich wohl ich leben ;) Deine Argumentation mit physisch greifbaren Produkten kann ich auch verstehen, aber nicht nachvollziehen. Ich glaube nämlich nicht, dass Unternehmensnamen davon abhängen, was sie jeweils herstellen. Und natürlich ist "Volkswagen" (das Unternehmen) nicht maskulin.

Answer (score 3):

That is a more complex question than you might think. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Genus-und-Numerus-bei-Firmennamen) has an elaborate page about it.

Not only the gender is relevant, but also the number (singular/plural).

1. Does the brand name carry already a gender? Use that one.

> *Die Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung*, *Die Rügenwalder Mühle*, ...

2. If not, you are free to choose between *das* and *die*, depending on whether you want to refer to *brand name* as **das Unternehmen *brand name*** or **die Firma *brand name***

> [Das Unternehmen] Microsoft hat hundert seiner Mitarbeiter entlassen / [Die Firma] Microsoft hat hundert ihrer Mitarbeiter entlassen

The words in the [brackets] can be obmitted.

3. If the brand name is used together with its legal structure and the latter is used as an apposition, you can still use the gender of the original enterprise

> Der Blumenhof OHG [...]

where OHG is short for *offene Handelsgesellschaft*

4. If the legal structure is part of the core name OR you don't want to use it as an apposition, you refer to the gender and number of the legal structure, i.e.

> Die Blumenhof OHG, die Techno-Studios-Gesellschaft mbh **sucht** (singular!)

5. For abbreviations there's often confusion about the number, e.g. BMW (Bayrische Motoren Werke, which itself is plural). Duden advices, that the abbreviation is often followed by third person singular declination. If the abbreviation is written in long form, things become clear again

> BMW hat seine Mitarbeiter entlassen / Die Bayrischen Motoren Werke stellen neue Mitarbeiter ein.

Comment: I am a bit hesitant to accept Duden's opinion on "Der Blumenhof ...-Gesellschaft" (would very probably accept "der" without the "OHG", though) and "BMW haben". Both sound wierd to me.

Answer (score 1):

For most companies, we don't use an article at all, so they are kind of genderless.

Examples:
"Microsoft hat ein neues Betriebssystem herausgebracht. Es gibt ein neues Betriebssystem von Microsoft"
"Viele Leute warten schon mit großer Vorfreude auf das neue iPhone von Apple."

The products on the other hand have articles:
"Hans fährt jetzt einen (der) Mercedes. Hans fährt jetzt einen Wagen von Mercedes Benz."
"Mein Bruder hat sich ein (das) iPhone gekauft. Mein Bruder hat sich ein Handy von Apple gekauft."